# How to access files in /META-INF/resources when module-info.java is present?

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system, module-info

When TestNG invokes [Class.getResourceAsStream()](https://github.com/testng-team/testng/blob/04e3e0fa7f8d93151dec408c936d1e27f85b56fe/testng-core/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/jq/Main.java#L109) on an external module, [it is returning null](https://github.com/testng-team/testng/issues/2727#issue-1128971797).

Per [Resources visibility with java9 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59020158/resources-visibility-with-java9-modules#comment104334989_59020158) when a user wants to access `/resources/someResource.xml` in a library that contains `module-info.java`, the module must `opens resources` unconditionally.

Fair enough. But what happens if a user wants to access `/META-INF/resources/someResource.xml` in such a library? What `opens` instruction is necessary in this case?

**UPDATE**:

The bug report was filed against version 7.5 of TestNG. I just noticed that if we [look at the source code](https://github.com/testng-team/testng/blob/release_7.5/testng-core/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/jq/Main.java#L107C71-L107C71) of that version we see it is trying to load `/META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js`.

Comment: *...  then the module must contain opens resources.* No - that's not necessary

Comment: What makes you think you need an `opens` instruction for reading resources? When I create two modules, one with a resource and one using it with `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/res/A.txt")`, I don't need any `opens` statements.

Comment: @g00se then how do you explain [this exception](https://github.com/testng-team/testng/issues/2727#issue-1128971797)? [Class.getResourceAsStream()](https://github.com/testng-team/testng/blob/04e3e0fa7f8d93151dec408c936d1e27f85b56fe/testng-core/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/jq/Main.java#L109) is returning `null` when looking up a resource in an external module.

Comment: Did you try using `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream` and the full resource name? Can you try to provide an [mcve]?

Comment: *@g00se then how do you explain this exception?* The path to the resource is wrong? In the exception message the resource name is simply the plain file name. That would mean it would have (generally) to be in the same package as the class that loaded it. That, needless to say, is not the correct state of affairs: that Javascript resource should be in a separate resource folder

Comment: @g00se I agree that the path looks wrong, but why would this code work fine on the classpath but break on the module path? Does Java include `/META-INF/resources` in the search path for non-modular code, but removes it for modular code? That seems odd.

Comment: Try to create a minimal reproducer (using the command line) of the issue and show that in your question. I assume there might be some `.class` file or similar in the `META-INF` directory.

Comment: `META-INF` is generally nothing to do with resources. To debug, I would print the value of system property `java.class.path` at the app's entry point

Comment: Are you maybe using multi-release JARs? Because these have `.class` files somewhere in the `META-INF` directory. Try without a multi-release build.

Comment: You might also want to make sure you are using a `Class` from the same `ClassLoader` the resource is located under as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my testing, opening the package is only necessary when **the file is in the same package as a class in the module**. In that case, you need to open the package of the class in the same module.

So, assume you have a project like the following:

```
|-A
| |-module-info.java
| |-a
|   |-A.java
|   |-x
|     |-X
|-B
  |-module-info.java
  |-b
    |-B.java
```

and `A/module-info.java`:

```java
module a {
    exports a;
}
```

as well as `B/module-info.java`:

```java
module b {
    requires a;
}
```

then compile it with the following commands:

```bash
cd A
javac module-info.java a\A.java
cd ..
cd B
javac --module-path ..\A module-info.java b\B.java
cd ..
```

The content of class `A` is irrelevant here (it just needs to exist and have a class/interface/enum/record/whatever declaration with the correct name).

We then let `B` read the file `a/x/X` from module `A`:

```java
package b;

import java.io.*;
import a.A;

public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(A.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("a/x/X")))){
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
        }
    }
}
```

When running it with

```java
java --module-path A;B -m b/b.B
```

it displays the first line of `a/x/X`.

However, we cannot access files in the same directory as the `A.class` file:

```java
package b;

import java.io.*;
import a.A;

public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(A.class.getResourceAsStream("A.java")))){
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
        }
    }
}
```

If we now add `opens a` in `A/module-info.java` (and recompile the module with the above command), the resource can be read.

If we want to read `/META-INF/a/A.txt` or similar (in the `A` module), no `opens` statement is required as there is no class in the same package.

Comment: You're right. Per https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String):

`If the resource is not in a package in the module then the resource is not encapsulated. [...] A resource name with the name "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" is never encapsulated because "META-INF" is not a legal package name.` I don't know what is going on with TestNG but this doesn't seem to have anything to do with Java Modules. Thank you for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Note that technically, you could have a class with an "illegal package name" but it cannot be created with `javac` (you'd need to create the class file differently) and it may be different for multi-release JARs where class files are located in subdirectories of `META-INF` (e.g. `META-INF/versions/<Java version>`).